# 'System.NullReferenceException' exception thrown

Tags: c#, exception, combobox, null

I have this error in my program on the next line of code...

```
private void btnGrabar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (tbNombres.Text.Trim().Length > 0) {
        contacto Persona = new contacto();
        if (temp == 0) {
            Persona.AgregarContacto(tbNombres.Text,
                                    tbDireccion.Text, tbTelefono.Text, tbCelular.Text, tbEmail.Text,
                                    fechaActual, Convert.ToInt32(cboProfesion.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                                    Convert.ToInt32(cboPais.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

the program is an organizer and you put info like name, cellphone, etc.
i think the problem can be on my combobox but I don't really now, please help, if you need me to put the whole code just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with SQL?  That looks *a lot* more like C# code than SQL code.

Comment: all the information that is going to be add on the organizer will be added to a database on sql

Answer (score 0):

A `NullReferenceException` means that somewhere in your code you try to access something that is undefined. The `.` operator causes this, when the word on the left of the operator is `null`.

Add breakpoints in your method, hover over the object and properties and try to find out, why which object or property is `null`.

These are basic debugging skills. Please have a look for how to debug an application; this will help you, here.

Comment: i don´t really know how to make breakpoints

Comment: See for example this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx